# What is the proper way to create TTaskBar instance at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Using Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1.

I want to create an instance of `TTaskBar` at runtime in a VCL application.  I found an interesting problem with `TTaskBar`:

```
var F: TForm;
    B: TTaskBar;
begin
  F := TForm.Create(Application);

  B := TTaskBar.Create(F);
  B.TabProperties := [TThumbTabProperty.CustomizedPreview];

  F.Show;
end;
```

The above code will raise an error: `Could not register tab. Error 0`.

But, this code works:

```
var F: TForm;
    B: TTaskBar;
begin
  F := TForm.Create(Application);
  F.Show;

  B := TTaskBar.Create(F);
  B.TabProperties := [TThumbTabProperty.CustomizedPreview];
end;
```

It seems that creating a `TTaskBar` instance for a hidden form is not allowed.

Comment: You did not say which version of Delphi you are using, but `TTaskBar` has had a lot of bugs over the years, and not all of them are fixed still, so you are best off simply not using it *AT ALL*. Use Microsoft's `ITaskbarList...` COM interfaces directly instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In `Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1`.  Subject has updated.  Thanks

Comment: As for the actual error, no you cannot register a tab for a hidden window. In fact, the `ITakbarList3` documentation specifically states that you have to wait until the window's taskbar button has been created before you can perform any `ITaskbarList3`-related operations, and that creation does not happen until the window is shown.

Comment: And also, even if the registration did succeed, one of `TTaskBar`'s bugs is that once it has been registered, updates made to the tab will throw that error even though the registration is still valid.